How to filter actual group name from bundle of StatusBarNotification using NotificationListenerService
enter image description here
I am reading notifications using NotificationListenerService, working fine, but i want to filter excat title as the name in application, eg - in whatsapp a user have name Deepesh, when he message in group, we get title in notification bundle like GroupName : ~Deepesh, GroupName (2 massages) : ~Deepesh ,
i want to extract actual group name like here is GroupName
I extract sender name using some conditions, like after : is sender and before is group name, but how group name because its sometimes with additional (x masseses) , if you think remove (x masseses) using regex expression, but on which condition, if i remove every time, may be group name is like GroupName(x massages) , and title comes GroupName (x masseses) (x masseses)
Then i got an idea, in that bundle messages list is available, so i get size, and put condition, if messageList size is great than 1 , then remove last (x masseses) , and its working fine, but but but when suddenly massage comes after break like internet open after some time, sometimes if message list size is 1 , still found additional added (x massages) in title, so I want any new hint, so i can filter actual group name
I have get messages list size from bundle, and found when size is grater than 1 , its added (x massages) , working fine but when suddenly more message comes, its sometimes showing (x masseses) when size is 1
also tried to get bundles and extract, but found only sender name, which is name, not group name
also extracted messangingUser
or almost tried to extract all keys value, but failed to solve
but same other apps on playstore what working like same have no issue
